# How to convert a stl vector of 3-element structs into 2D C-style array

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

Suppose I have the following simple struct:

```
struct Vector3
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

and I create a list of vertices:

```
std::vector<Vector3> verticesList;
```

In addition to this I need to use a third-party library. The library has a function with the following signature:

```
typedef double[3] Real3;
external void createMesh(const Real3* vertices, const size_t verticesCount);
```

What is the best way to convert `verticesList` into something which could be passed into `createMesh()` as the `vertices` parameter?

At the moment I use the following approach:

```
static const size_t MAX_VERTICES = 1024;

if (verticesList.size() > MAX_VERTICES)
    throw std::exception("Number of vertices is too big");

Real3 rawVertices[MAX_VERTICES];
for (size_t vertexInd = 0; vertexInd < verticesList.size(); ++vertexInd)
{
    const Vector3& vertex = verticesList[vertexInd];

    rawVertices[vertexInd][0] = vertex.x;
    rawVertices[vertexInd][1] = vertex.y;
    rawVertices[vertexInd][2] = vertex.z;
}

createMesh(rawVertices, verticesList.size());
```

But surely it is not the best way to solve the issue.

Comment: That approach has the virtue of being quite readable. You may find that an array of Vector3 is arranged in memory in exactly the same way as an array of floats; a reinterpret cast or memcpy might solve your problem in a more brief fashion. I am too lazy to check this myself, however.

Comment: I would imagine you could implement a conversion operator for `Vector3->Real3` and pass `&verticesList[0]`.

Comment: @chris: A conversion from `Vector3`->`Real3` would not convert from `Vector3*`->`Real3*`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Oops, right. I was thinking of the `reinterpet_cast`, but a conversion seemed more appropriate (if it would work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is *one* proper way of doing it. There are also some other ways...

The type `Vector3` is layout compatible with the type `Real3`, the implication of this is that you can force casting a pointer to one type to a pointer of the other:

```
createMesh( reinterpret_cast<Real3*>(&verticesList[0]), vertices.size() );
```

Other alternative, as Rook mentions, to remove the loop is using `memcpy`, since the types are POD:

```
Real3 rawVertices[MAX_VERTICES];
std::memcpy( rawVertices, &verticesList[0], 
             vertices.size()*sizeof verticesList[0] );
```

This is more concise, and probably more efficient, but it still is copying the whole container.

---

I believe that the standard does guarantee this behavior (at least C++11), two standard layout and standard compatible types have the same memory layout (duh?), and §9.2p19 states:

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

This guarantee technically means something slightly different than what I claimed before:  you can `reinterpret_cast<double*>(&verticesList[0])` points to `verticesList[0].x`. But it also implies that the conversion from `double*` to `Real3` pointer through reinterpret cast will also be fine.

Comment: reinterpret_cast on other thing than void* and integral types or integral types pointers is UB unless you cast it back to its original type.

Comment: Of course, reinterpret_cast is the fastest and the shortest way to do this, but it's apparently error-prone. For example, it would be almost impossible to find incorrect casting, if I decided to change double in Vector3 to float.

Comment: @JoelFalcou: The above quote from C++11 standard seems to disagree with you and explicitly state that `reinterpret_cast` from a standard-layout type to the first member and back is well defined. Furthermore, 5.2.10p7 states: *When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v)) if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout types*, which seems again to provide well defined semantics.

Comment: @DmitrySapelnikov: Agreed, it is the second most dangerous cast in the language (following the c-style cast only because it can actually be a `reinterpret_cast` under the hood, allows to cast away const-ness and does not cryout as *beware* when browsing code). Extra care needs to be taken when dealing with `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: I stand corrected then, this is probably an upgrade of the stadnard with respect to this practice. Consider me updtaed as well. Thanks.